# jquery changing xml parameters on the

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been asked to put together a Santa Tracker... by Thursday:) so far what I have found is a google map api that would draw markers on the map based on a MYSQL db. It is working and does the job. What it does can put all the planned point on the map.

I wonder if it is easy to change the marker with JQuery one by one. So when Santa passes a location the marker would change.

Could someone kindly help me out how to do it? basically the before and after parameters need to be changed with a little delay.

Many thanks for the good people in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      after: {
        icon: 'http://localhost/google/santa.png'
      },
      before: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.57185, -0.20962),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("map.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 786px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is used xml and set a flag visited = yes, and then pulled the next record.  you can also implement a timer that would check the xml every 30 mins say, and update your map.

this way you would have set the "lat" and "lng" variables